# Can't run a command in PowerShell because of single quote

Tags: windows, powershell

When I try to run the command

```
iex (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

in order to install [Scoop](http://scoop.sh/) I can't execute it because I can't get the right escaping of the string with the open single quote at the beginning, look at the picture for a better understanding.

I'm on Windows 7, how do I solve it? I don't have two different single quotes on my keyboard (italian keyboard layout).

[image: If you see the open quote is corrupted but I only have that on my Keyboard]

Comment: Quoting isn't your issue at all. The script downloads successfully, then fails to execute `iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring($core_url)` (which, according to the source, points at `https://raw.github.com/lukesampson/scoop/master/lib/core.ps1`). And that fails because there's a plain old bug in that script that the parser chokes on (`if(7zip_installed) {`). You may want to report this to the author.

Comment: You really should add english translations of the errors you are presenting. Google translate gets me 'constante numerica errata' - >
'Wrong numeric constant' which is odd since you are talking about quotes. THat should not be an issue here. I don't think that is your issue.

Comment: Yeah and avoid screenshots, instead post it as quote, so one can just copy paste it into the translator.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Omg thanks, I didn't grasp it, thanks, I will see if I can work around that

Comment: Addendum: `if (7zipinstalled) {` is actually legal syntax, I spoke too soon. The issue is still that something is failing in the execution of the downloaded script(s), but probably not that line.